# How to get method argument names when invoke a method in Java

Tags: java

For example:

I have a method defined like these:

```
class MyController extends Controller {

   public void index() {
       String aa = "1111";
       int bb = 122;

       render("index.html", aa, bb);
   }
}
```

Now, I want to get the argument names: aa and bb to build a HashMap:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.set("aa", aa);
map.set("bb", bb);
```

I seen many MVC frameworks can do so, how implemented? reflection or byte code hacking or compile-time processing?

PS: I known how to get method parameter names(by compiling with debug), but I need know method argument names when invocation.

Comment: That is not possible. I think.

Comment: The first argument, the literal, doesn't even have a 'name'. Ergo what you are asking is meaningless.

Comment: Please show an example of an MVC framework doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your MVC framework does something else. 
It probably extracts the names of method parameters using reflection. 
For example if your method render is defined as

`void render(String file, String a, String b)`

your framework (and you) can get the names of parameters 'a' and 'b'. I doubt someone can get names of local method variables `aa` and `bb` as they are written in your example.

Yet another way to get some data about the parameter names is using annotations. You can define custom annotation (let's call it `@Param`) and then use it as following:

`render(@Param("fileName") "index.html", @Param("aa") "aaaaa", @Param("bb") "bbbb");`

Now you can extract the parameter name using reflection API. The annotations may be used either when on method definition or method call.

This is how Spring MVC works.

Comment: You mean the method parameter names in method signature, I mean the actual argument names when invocation. They's not different

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the `render()` method to find out the variable names of its arguments?

That is impossible without bytecode manipulation.

MVC frameworks can know the argument names, when they get a string containing the call expression (e.g. in JSF and other web frameworks), but not when they get some bytecode containing the actual call.

Comment: but the aa or bb variable is not managed by framework, they are completely specified by user code.

These can be easily implemented:

void index(ServletRequest request, String queryString1, int postParameter2) {
....}

Comment: @JockYang I don't understand. Which "These" do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Atually, you are never going to see any framework reading the names of arguments. They work at the level of object properties -- instance fields, getters and setters. You can find those at runtime with reflection. If you would like to roll your own facility that eliminates boilerplate, you'll still have to redesign to use the names of object properties.